# eclipse to list functions in current file (via Ctrl+O)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

when I do ctrl+O in eclipse, it gives list of all symbols in the current file.  Which is not much useful for me all the time.

Is there a way to configure it saying list only the function and global variables (kind of) ?